# Opencart 1.5.6 Admin login slow

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

I am new to opencart shopping cart, I installed it successfully on my test server, but a moment i am trying to signin to admin panel, it takes around 40 to 50 minutes to sign in.

I debug the code and come to know that , upon each login request , opencart send curl request 
to yahoo server to get currencies values following method demonstrates the same.

```
public function updateCurrencies($force = false) {
    if (extension_loaded('curl')) {
        $data = array();

        if ($force) {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "currency WHERE code != '" . $this->db->escape($this->config->get('config_currency')) . "'");
        } else {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "currency WHERE code != '" . $this->db->escape($this->config->get('config_currency')) . "' AND date_modified < '" .  $this->db->escape(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 day'))) . "'");
        }

        foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
            $data[] = $this->config->get('config_currency') . $result['code'] . '=X';
        }   

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=' . implode(',', $data) . '&f=sl1&e=.csv');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $content = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        $lines = explode("\n", trim($content));

        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            $currency = utf8_substr($line, 4, 3);
            $value = utf8_substr($line, 11, 6);

            if ((float)$value) {
                $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "currency SET value = '" . (float)$value . "', date_modified = '" .  $this->db->escape(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) . "' WHERE code = '" . $this->db->escape($currency) . "'");
            }
        }

        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "currency SET value = '1.00000', date_modified = '" .  $this->db->escape(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) . "' WHERE code = '" . $this->db->escape($this->config->get('config_currency')) . "'");

        $this->cache->delete('currency');
    }
}
```

I skipped this step by setting update currencies in opencart to 'no' , and resolved the issue ,now it takes only a second to get sign in on backend.

My question is , is it really necessary to update the currencies in opencart?

Comment: I've never heard about such an issue. I'm also using Opencart 1.5.6. Updating currencies is necessary as their values keep on changing. Please check again in a fresh opencart installation. If you still have the issue then remove the code related to the issue you found and write a cronjob for updating currency values.

Comment: Hmm, I am also using 1.5.6 and didn't realize it. And I think it is kind of an overkill to check the currencies on each request. It would be fairly enough to just test it once a day (in the morning, e.g.) by a cron job. And anyway, it is not necessary to let my currency rates be updated from outside - I may wish to use the same currency rates all along the year (for easier accounting at the end). So the possibility to switch this off is fine. But I still cannot believe that Daniel would implement loading of currencies from Yahoo on each simple request... -_+

Comment: @Sankar , I tried 4 to 5 times installation for opencart 1.5.6 , but still issue persists, And yes i think its good to go with cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

Issue may come if it is not able to make connection to Yahoo server because no timeout statement is there.